# Any idea how to find a website written on ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Any idea how to find a website written on ROR?

I mean just looking at urls ... how I can identify the written in ROR ?

Thanks for your time .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just looking at URLs? Impossible. Most Rails apps these days have this:

```
<meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/>
<meta name="csrf-token" content="y3DSVtX1Q2ZFviGXhCWCjjFaoRJImq7hJAWrZugudLU="/>
```

You could check the HTML source for that.

Comment: Also can check for `<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />` inside a `<form>`. No guarantee it's RoR but a good clue.

Answer (score 0):

No way by looking at URLs, and I'm pretty sure it's also impossible by looking at source code since it's all HTML.